# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier, not sure how the code is wrong

Tags: javascript

```
function goOneYear() {
        //changing the value of the no rabbits entree
        var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("numRabbits").value) + parseInt(document.getElementById("rateBirth").value) * birthRate - parseInt(document.getElementById("rateDeath").value) * deathRate;
        if (x < 2000) {
          alert("FOX HUNT");
        }
        document.getElementById("numRabbits").value = x;
        //incementing year by 1
        document.getElementById("numYears").value++;
        //adding this year to the list
        var temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < parseInt(document.getElementById("numRabbits").value); i++) {
          temp += "*";
        }
        printTable.push(document.getElemernyById("numYears").value + " " + temp);
        //making the text area the new set
        if (document.getElementById("drawGraph").checked == true) {
          if (temp.length > document.getElementById("rabbitTable").cols) {
            document.getElementById("rabbitTable").cols = temp.length;
          }
          document.getElementById("rabbitTable").rows = printTable.length;
          changeTextArea();
        }
        //setting conditions back to normal
        setRabbitConditions(document.getElementById("normal"));
        setRates("normal");
      }
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you really should put those DOM elements into variables, instead of repeatedly calling `document.getElementById`. You've got some really long lines that don't need to be.

Comment: Well the error should tell you the line that has the syntax error. Look at that line of code and make sure you have the syntax correct.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have an `int` keyword. Variables can be declared with `var` or `let` and the type is specified entirely by the value that's assigned.

Answer (score 1):

use `var i = 0` instead of `int i = 0`